# How can I change the style of cursor only when another element is being hovered over?

Tags: javascript, html, css, cursor

I'm trying to code a custom cursor that changes its style when hovering over certain elements.

As shown in my code, I tried to define a function that changed the cursor's style when hovering over the div, calling on it using `<div id="control" onmouseover="cursorFill()></div>"`. I expected the cursor to change on hover and change back once it was no longer over the div, but instead it changed and did not change back.

I would prefer to do this in vanilla JavaScript if possible (without jQuery or other extensions).

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
})

function cursorFill() {
  document.getElementById("cursor").style.backgroundColor = "#fff";
}
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

#cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

#control {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  margin-top: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor"></div>
<div id="control" onmouseover="cursorFill()"></div>
```

Comment: there is no corresponding function to revert it back to its original state when the mouse leaves the div.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using JS to do this instead of CSS? [Hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) works very well.

Comment: I didn't realize there was a way to do this with CSS. Could you clarify?

Comment: Use the :hover pseudo-class. It's the link in my comment.

Comment: I'm not trying to change the `div#control`'s style, I'm trying to change the cursor's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you only set the background colour when the mouse is over `#control`. It needs to be re-set back to its original value when the mouse *leaves* the element too.

Note in the following example that I removed the inline `onmouseover` attribute, as using these is bad practice and should be avoided. Use unobrusive event handlers in your JS instead.

Also note that I amended the logic to add/remove a CSS class from the element. This is to avoid having any CSS logic in your JS code.

Lastly, I changed the event from `mouseover`, which fires once for *every pixel* the mouse hovers over the element, and as such is overkill for this use case, to `mouseenter`, which only fires once when the mouse first enters the boundary of the target element.

With those changes made, your code would look something like this:

```js
const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');
const control = document.querySelector('#control');

document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
  cursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
})

control.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => cursor.classList.add('over'));
control.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => cursor.classList.remove('over'));
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: none;
}

body {
  background-color: #000;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

#cursor {
  position: fixed;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 5px solid #fff;
  background-color: transparent;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  pointer-events: none;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
#cursor.over {
  background-color: #FFF;
} 

#control {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 10em;
  height: 10em;
  margin-top: 50vh;
}
```

```html
<div id="cursor"></div>
<div id="control"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: No problem, glad to help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the events mouseenter and mouseleave to achieve that, here is an example :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <style>
    * {
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      box-sizing: border-box;
      cursor: none;
    }

    body {
      background-color: #000;
      align-items: center;
      justify-content: center;
      display: flex;
    }

    #cursor {
      position: fixed;
      width: 20px;
      height: 20px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      border: 5px solid #fff;
      background-color: transparent;
      transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
      pointer-events: none;
      mix-blend-mode: difference;
    }

    #control {
      background-color: #fff;
      width: 10em;
      height: 10em;
      margin-top: 50vh;
    }
  </style>
  <title>Cursor Example</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
  <div id="control"></div>
  <script>
    const cursor = document.querySelector('#cursor');
    const control = document.querySelector('#control');

    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
      cursor.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
      cursor.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
    });

    control.addEventListener('mouseenter', cursorFill);
    control.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
      cursor.style.backgroundColor = 'transparent';
    });

    function cursorFill() {
      cursor.style.backgroundColor = '#fff';
    }
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```